# How can I call a specific object based off cin c++

Tags: c++

So I am trying to eliminate how I reiterate the same code in my switch statement the only difference being what object is getting the getAnswer() method. Any help is appreciated

```
#include "main.hpp"
#include "toolbox.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

Problem1 problem1;
Problem2 problem2;
Problem3 problem3;
Problem4 problem4;
Problem5 problem5;
Problem6 problem6;
Problem7 problem7;
Problem8 problem8;
Problem9 problem9;
Problem10 problem10;
Problem11 problem11;
Problem12 problem12;
Problem13 problem13;
Problem14 problem14;
Problem15 problem15;
Problem16 problem16;

void Execute::print() {
    int choice;
do {
    std::cout << "Please enter the # of the problem you would like to solve: ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem1.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem2.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem3.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem4.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem5.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem6.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 7:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem7.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem8.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 9:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem9.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 10:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem10.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 11:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem11.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 12:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem12.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 13:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem13.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 14:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem14.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 15:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem15.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case 16:
    {
        auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << problem16.getAnswer() << std::endl;
        auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    default: std::cout << "Problem does not exist or is not solved yet" << std::endl;
    }

} while (choice != 17);
```

}

I am very new to programming and am simply looking for a solution that allows me to pick the correct class object and print it out without having this large switch statement that takes up way too much space

Comment: Does every problem have to be a different class type? Could you not just define a class Problem and store some sort of array of problems and iterate over it in a loop?

Beyond that, you have a ton of redundant code in your switch statement. You could easily move the creation of timePoint1 to before the switch and everything after the cout of the problem to outside of the switch.

Comment: thank you for this, it was put together very rough to just try to make the program run at a more user friendly pace really

Answer (score 5):

Use a function template and move the details to the function template.

```
template <typename Problem>
void getAnswer(Problem& prob)
{
   auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << prob.getAnswer() << std::endl;
   auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

void Execute::print() {
   int choice;
   do {
      std::cout << "Please enter the # of the problem you would like to solve: ";
      std::cin >> choice;
      std::cout << std::endl;

      switch (choice)
      {
         case 1:
         {
            getAnswer(problem1);
            break;
         }

         case 2:
         {
            getAnswer(problem2);
            break;
         }

         // etc.
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of switch you can have a map of function pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <map>
class Problem1
{
public:
    int getAnswer() {return 1;}
};
class Problem2
{
public:
    int getAnswer() {return 1;}
};

template<typename Problem>
void f(){
    Problem problem;
    auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << problem.getAnswer() << std::endl;
    auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    int choice = 1;
    const std::map<int,void(*)(void)> choices{
        {1,f<Problem1>},
        {2,f<Problem2>}
    };

    auto pf = choices.find(choice);
    if(pf != choices.end()){
        (pf->second)();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this but not certain where my implementation is wrong for this method

could it be that in my other cpp's of problem 1-16 getAnswer() is a string and not an int (i tried switching the map declaration to this but that didn't help)

Comment: @Chris P getAnswer type has no importance to the rest of the code. I have included it just to make the code compilable. Its return type could be changed to string without changing anything else

Answer (score 0):

"With a bit of boilerplate", we can remove the switch statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

struct Problem1 {
    int getAnswer();
};

struct Problem2 {
    std::string getAnswer();
};

template <typename Problem>
void getAnswer(Problem& prob)
{
   auto timePoint1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << prob.getAnswer() << std::endl;
   auto timePoint2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << static_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(timePoint2 - timePoint1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

template<class Tuple, std::size_t N>
void call_nth_answer(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    getAnswer(std::get<N>(tuple));
}

template<class ProblemTuple, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto makeAnswerTable(ProblemTuple&& problems, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    auto constexpr N = sizeof...(Is);
    constexpr auto call_table = std::array<void(*)(ProblemTuple&), N>
    {
        &call_nth_answer<ProblemTuple, Is>...
    };
    return call_table;
}

template<class ProblemTuple>
bool dispatch_nth_answer(ProblemTuple&& problems, std::size_t i)
{
    using tuple_type = std::decay_t<ProblemTuple>;
    auto constexpr N = std::tuple_size<tuple_type>::value;

    static constexpr auto call_table = makeAnswerTable(problems, std::make_index_sequence<N>());

    if (i < 0 || !(i < N)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        call_table[i](problems);
        return true;
    }
}


template<class Problems>
void print(Problems&& problems) {
    using problem_tuple = std::decay_t<Problems>;

   int choice;
   do {
      std::cout << "Please enter the # of the problem you would like to solve: ";
      std::cin >> choice;
      std::cout << std::endl;

      if (!dispatch_nth_answer(problems, choice - 1))
      {
          std::cout << "invalid choice" << std::endl;
          break;
      }
   } while(1);
}

int main()
{
    Problem1 problem1;
    Problem2 problem2;
    print(std::tie(problem1, problem2));
}
```